# TypeError: pouchdb_1.default is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, pouchdb

I've used PouchDB on browser based projects before and everything was alright, but on a new node project I get this error no matter how I import the module

Pouchdb 6.3.4 + @types/pouchdb

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
this.userDB = new PouchDB('db');
//TypeError: pouchdb_1.default is not a constructor
```

Resulting code:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const pouchdb_1 = require("pouchdb");
this.userDB = new pouchdb_1.default('db')
```

I've tried to import in all possible ways (import =, const =, import * as, import { })

**THE ANSWER (thanks to Mustansir Zia)**

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
```

Comment: Wow! A pleasure to have answered really. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PouchDB's [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb).

```
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
var db = new PouchDB('my_db');
```

Let's see if it works out using require. Babel doesn't have to append the `.default` to it in that case.

Comment: Hm! So I've changed it to 

const PouchDB = require('pouchdb');

and magically now it works. I was pretty sure I tried it before, but had problems with accessing PouchDB types (I'm on typescript here)

Thanks :)

Comment: That should do too. You're welcome! The reason why I prefer JS to TS. :)

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to install the typing :

```sh
npm i -D @types/pouchdb
```

and import as follow :

```js
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

after what everything works as expected :

```js
this.db = new PouchDB('my_db');
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `@types/pouchdb": "^6.3.2"` to the package.json in the devDependencies section.